# TypeError: ProductManager is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, backend

i have a file in JS where i define a constructor and some methods ( add, get, etc)
when i try to call it from another JS file i receive the message from the title: *TypeError: ProductManager is not a constructor*

```
const fs = require('fs')
const filename = './productos.json'

class ProductManager {
    products

    constructor() {
        this.products = []
    }

    #generateID = () => {
        if (this.products.length === 0) return 1
        return this.products[this.products.length - 1].id + 1
    }

    addProduct(title, description, price, image, code, stock) {
        const id = this.#generateID()
        const product = {id, title, description, price, image, code, stock}

        // Valido que el producto tenga todos los campos
        if (!title || !description || !price || !image || !code || !stock) {
            return console.log('Error: Todos los campos son obligatorios')
        }

        //Valido que el producto ingresado no exista
        const productExists = this.products.some((product) => product.code === code)
        if (productExists) {
            return console.log('Error: El producto ya existe')
        } else {
            this.products.push(product)
            fs.writeFileSync(filename, JSON.stringify(this.products, null, '\t'))
        }
    }

    getProducts() {

        // return this.#products

        const contenido = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(filename, 'utf-8'))
        console.log(" Muestro el contenido del archivo Productos", contenido)
    }
```

The second file where i call this JS is:

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

const ProductManager = require('./productos.js');

app.get('/', (request, response) => {
    response.send('<h1 style="color:goldenrod">Bienvenidos a la pagina de productos!!</h1>');
})

app.get('/products', (request, response) => {
    const productManager = new ProductManager()
    productManager.getProducts()
    response.send({
        message: "success",
        data: productManager.getProducts()
    })
})


app.listen(8080, () => {
    console.log("Servidor corriendo en http://localhost:8080");
})
```

the error is on the line  const productManager = new ProductManager()

i don't know where to start.

Comment: You need to show the `export` statement in `productos.js`.

Comment: Thanks Barmar. Can you tell me please where i have to EXPORT?

Comment: The file should end with something like `export ProductManager;`

Comment: I think i found it with: module.exports = ProductManager

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to change how you are exporting `ProductManager`. There are two ways to export something from a file - either as a default export, or as a named export. A default export looks like this:

```js
// file MyClassDefault.js
class MyClass {}
export default MyClass
```

A named export looks like this:

```js
// file MyClassNamed.js
class MyClass
export MyClass
```

The difference is in how you import them:

```js
MyClass = require('MyClassDefault.js') // default export
{ MyClass } = require('MyClassNamed.js') // named export
```

You can only have one default export from a file, but you can have several named exports. Generally you want to use a consistent format across your project so it's easy to remember how to `require()` things.